# UISlider as an element of a UIContextMenu

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, mac-catalyst

Looking to put UISliders in a context menu.  Can't find anyway to do it, just simple UIActions.

Comment: Nope. Can't be done. You'll have to implement your own custom little popup.